# Pin fixed div to the right side of centered main div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

There are two divs, one is `.main` for primary content; one is `.aside` for some design decorations.

I only want to show aside on desktops, so I put it in media queries. When the viewport is exactly 1000px, you can see the aside pins to the right side of main perfectly without any gap or overlap.

[image]

But when it's larger than 1000px, they will start overlapping, which I don't want it to happen. **Is there a way to maintain the relationship of the two divs responsively with just CSS, or do I need JS?** In other words, aside's left edge always attaches to main's right edge.

I tried using `calc()`, but was unable to find the correct math formula. Also note, `position:fixed` for aside is required, as in the real case it targets much larger screens, elements are larger, and horizontal scrollbar should never be triggered.

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvRmro)**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .aside {
    position: fixed;
    left: 700px;
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="aside"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `left: calc(50% + 200px);` on the `aside` element, this will always put it 200px right of the horizontal center:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .aside {
    position: fixed;
    left: calc(50% + 200px);
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="aside"></div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify where the `200px`  is from in the `calc`?

Comment: @Stickers half the width of the main. since the main is in the center so from the center we have 200px on each side

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, my head is so big  right now as the real case is kind of complicated.

Comment: @Stickers so show us the real case and we will get it ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I will come back to this, I know you're on the other answer by the way.

Comment: @Stickers yes but at the start i though you want the element to be inside so i came up with the first formula and then added an update for the outsite ... but i guess this one is more optimized if you want to consider your trick ;)

Comment: I accepted this for its simplicity. Good to know calc can be nested. Thanks @TemaniAfif for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below formula. Your `main` has max-width of 400px and the width of the screen is 100% so the margin in both sides are `(100% - 400px)` and we divide by 2 to get only one side.

*You can also introduce CSS variable in order to better handle this*

```css
:root {
  --main-width: 400px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  max-width: var(--main-width);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .aside {
    position: fixed;
    right: calc((100% - var(--main-width)) / 2);
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="aside"></div>
```

And if you want the `aside` to be **outside** simply remove its width from the previous calculation:

```css
:root {
  --main-width: 400px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  max-width: var(--main-width);
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: pink;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .aside {
    position: fixed;
    right: calc(calc((100% - var(--main-width)) / 2) - 200px);
    top: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="aside"></div>
```

Same logic if you want to apply this to the left side.

```
((100% - width of main) / 2) - width of aside
```

Or

```
50% - (width of main/2) - width of aside
```